# Custom Category Field in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii, form-control, active-form

I'm modifying a classified application made in the Yii framework. The application already includes category-based fields, Now I want to trigger another input field with the same code. I tried adding the $('.price-type').show(); in JS. But it didn't help.

JS File

```
    $(document).on('click','#modal-category .modal-footer #success-selection',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#choose-class').text($(this).data('selectedText'));
    $('input#listing-category_id').val($(this).data('selectedId'));

    $.post($('#category-fields').data('url'),{
        category_id:$(this).data('selectedId'),
        listing_id:$('#post-form').data('listing'),
    },function (json) {
        if(json.html) {
            $('.category-fields').show();
            $('.price-types').show();
            $('#category-fields').html(json.html);
            $('select').select2({
                width: '100%',
                language: site.language,
                dir: site.dir,
            });
        }else{
            $('.category-fields').hide();
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

Form.php

```
<div class="row price-types" id="price-types" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <?= $form->field($ad, 'pricetype', [
            'template'      => '{input} {error}',
        ])->textInput(['placeholder' => t('app', 'Price Type'), 'class' => 'form-control'])->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row category-fields" id="category-fields" data-url="<?= url(['/listing/get-category-fields']); ?>" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Comment: please share  whole code i think its issue related to event is not binded or dom element doesnt find. Please try to do on console so that you will get the error as share the complete screenshot and code here so that w e can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

```
$(document). ready(function() {
$('.price-types').hide();
});
```

instead of using style="display: none" for the div and then you can unhide the element as :

```
$('.price-types').show();
```

on any desired event.